# how to implement CORBA AMI on java

Tags: java, corba, amazon-ami, orb

I have a corba server written on java, (using standard ORB and idlj that came with JDK).
Also, I have a corba client written on C++ using ACE/TAO. Now I have to write same client, but on java.

However, I've found that idlj do not support AMI (async method invocation). 
What is a best way cope with this problem?

is there any way to implement AMI with 'standard jdk'? 
my be I have use 3rd party orb implementation? In this case, could you please advise me something that present in maven repositories, so the integration will easy for me.

Thank you.

Comment: You're rather likely to have to pay for this, rather than just get it from a Maven repository. You'll have to search the CORBA vendors.

Answer (score 0):

[JacORB](http://www.jacorb.org/features.html), a free (GPL2 licenced), ORB that supports AMI. But I don't know any public available mvn repo for it.